# What happens if I change the norm of an absolute convergent series?

Tags: normed-spaces, absolute-convergence

Let us consider the topological vector space $\mathbb{C}$ equipped with the euclidean topology.

We know that a series of complex numbers $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is said to be *absolutely convergent* iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||a_n||$ is convergent.

I've always assumed that by $||\cdot||$ we mean, when considering absolute convergence, the euclidean norm. Now that I'm reviewing my notes, I'm wondering why we usually make this assumption.
What happens if I consider different kinds of norm?

In particular I'd like to know

- Does absolute convergence depend on the choice of $||\cdot||$ ?
- If I change the norm, does absolute convergence still imply
  convergence?
- Is there any book or paper addressing this question?

Comment: So long as $\mathbb{C}$ is still complete with respect to your norm, convergence will hold under absolute convergence (indeed, absolute convergence makes your series Cauchy). Example : $\ell^p$ norm (on $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: As I said, I wasn't thinking about changing the norm defining the topology. I'm thinking about changing just the norm appearing in the absolute convergence definition (e.g., if $\sum||a_n||$ is convergent w.t.r. to the euclidean topology, is $\sum[a_n^3]^{1/3}$ still convergent w.t.r. to the euclidean topology?

Comment: All norms are equivalent ($\exists A,B>0:\ A\|\cdot\|_1\leq \|\cdot\|_2\leq B\|\cdot\|_1$), in finite dimension.

Comment: I'm NOT considering different topologies, but rather different norms. The notion of absolute convergence actually involves $two$ norms: one defining the topology, and the other defining what "absolute" means. I'm just wondering what happens if I change the latter without changing the former, i.e., wondering if the convergence of $\sum[a_n^m]^{1/m}$ still implies the convergence of $\sum a_n$ for every $m$

Comment: Read carefully. You are being given a pair of inequalities. Only you are talking about different topologies.